# TypeError: $.ajaxCall is not a function

Tags: javascript, php

i have some issue when ajax call we got error are `TypeError: $.ajaxCall is not a function` .when we call function on page there are some issue .
my code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jscript/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function kidclick(viewid,ageid,type) {
  alert(viewid);alert(ageid);alert(type);
  $.ajaxCall('blog.ageViewId', 'ageId=' +ageid+ '&viewId=' +viewid+ '&type=' +type)     
}

</script>
```

Please some one solved my issue.

Comment: Have you defined jQuery in your HTML ?

Comment: For jQuery, it's `$.ajax()`, not `$.ajaxCall()`.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

For jquery, the right syntax is $.ajax. Not $.ajaxcall

Answer (score 0):

use below code.try **$.ajaxCall to $.ajax**

```
function kidclick(viewid,ageid,type) 
{ alert(viewid);
alert(ageid);
alert(type); 
$.ajax('blog.ageViewId', 'ageId=' +ageid+ '&viewId=' +viewid+ '&type=' +type)
}
```

Comment: @anil gupta this may help you :)